# how to display between dates amcharts using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, amcharts

In my requirement I need to display the details means the doc start date and expiry date like that. I am using am charts, but I am unable to display between dates details.

Below is my code:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "none",
  "type": "serial",
  "startDuration": 2,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "20-10-05,
    "visits": "15-03-03",
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }, {
    "country": "15-03-03",
    "visits": "20-10-05,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "left",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.85,
    "lineAlpha": 0.1,
    "type": "column",
    "topRadius": 1,
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "depth3D": 40,
  "angle": 30,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: If you have codepen link you can add it as an addition to code, but question should contain code, because links may become dead and your question would become not useful for future readers

Comment: i added code in this question also. will you please try to solve this

Comment: Your shared javascript code has sytnax errors.

Comment: Ok.  Will you please try to solve those errors please